# What is the name of the dumbbell that is semi-flexible in the middle?

Tags: weightlifting

I've seen videos of people using dumbbells that are somewhat flexible in the middle. I've only seen ones that are 1, 2, 3 pds. Each time, they were used for upper body injury rehab.

Is there a name for these special dumbbells? Google is giving me results that are not at all what I am thinking of. I'd really want to see a youtube video to confirm I am buying what I want. I want very light weight that flexes in the middle for upper body rehab.

**NOTE**:
The premise is that these dumbbells need to be easy / safer to move when not in use. The user is injured / hobbled / old. So, minimal weight at both ends is ideal. Because the resistance generated by momentum is only there when you need it (while doing rehab exercises), and not there at any other time.

My best explanation:
Imagine a normal dumbbell. Increase the length by maybe 50%. Allow the middle to be semi-flexible. Doing normal dumbbell exercise with that will make the weight feel much heavier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about [Shake Weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_Weight)?

[image: Shake Weight]

Or perhaps [Softgrip Flexible Weights](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LN69NW)?

[image: Softgrip weights]

They were created for physical therapy.

> SoftGrip Flexible Hand Weights were the brainchild of a physical therapy patient who was having trouble using the rigid, 2 lb. dumbbells prescribed to her. What arose: a comfortable, non-intimidating Hand Weight that’s easy to grasp and great for light workouts. Soft, but not floppy and color-coded for identification, SoftGrip Hand Weights are perfect for working out and rehabilitation.

Comment: Neither is what I'm looking for. But that Shake Weight looks awesome.

Comment: @imaichiko: It is not. http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/shake-weight-review#1

The one that you are looking for... it's more like regular weights on either side of a flexible bar?

Comment: yeah. After a little more thinking, now I'm convinced that you are correct. I just saw the rehab my friend was doing, and then a distant memory of the Shake Weight popped in my head. Sorry about my confusion.

Comment: Ah. Well, I'm glad I could help.